# Automate Quantity of any Items Using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutomateQty()
If Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("E4", Range("E4").End(xlDown)) = "Sheet1" Then

Dim val1 As String
    Dim val2 As String

    Set Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B4", Range("B4").End(xlDown)) = val1
    Set Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:B4", Range("A4:B4").End(xlDown)) = val2

    Dim Result As Integer

    Result = StrComp(val1, val2, vbTextCompare)

    If Result = True And Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C4", Range("C4").End(xlDown)) <> "" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4", Range("C4").End(xlDown)).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4", Range("C4").End(xlDown)). _
        Value + Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C4", Range("C4").End(xlDown)).Value
    Else
    If Result = True And Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D4", Range("D4").End(xlDown)) <> "" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D4", Range("D4").End(xlDown)).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D4", Range("D4").End(xlDown)). _
        Value + Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D4", Range("D4").End(xlDown)).Value
    End If

ElseIf Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("E4", Range("E4").End(xlDown)) = "Sheet2" Then

    Dim val1 As String
    Dim val2 As String

    Set Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B4", Range("D4").End(xlDown)) = val1
    Set Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A4:B4", Range("A4:B4").End(xlDown)) = val2

    Dim Result As Integer

    Result = StrComp(val1, val2, vbTextCompare)

    If Result = True And Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C4", Range("C4").End(xlDown)) <> "" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C4", Range("C4").End(xlDown)).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C4", Range("C4").End(xlDown)). _
        Value + Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C4", Range("C4").End(xlDown)).Value
    Else
    If Result = True And Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D4", Range("D4").End(xlDown)) <> "" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D4", Range("D4").End(xlDown)).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D4", Range("D4").End(xlDown)). _
        Value + Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D4", Range("D4").End(xlDown)).Value
    End If

Else
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Kindly check my VBA Code It shows a compile error of elseif statement. I hope I'll get the solution as soon as possible. Thank You

Comment: You need proper [indentation](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation), as well as a read of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements. You can't do `If...Else...ElseIf`.

Comment: Thank you BigBen but I just used nested if then elseif statement, it will be very much appreciated if you correct it. Thank you.

Comment: No you didn't... Please fix your indentation and check again.

Comment: `If Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("E4", Range("E4").End(xlDown)) = "Sheet1"` the value of the range will be a 2-D array, not a single value.

Comment: Hey thanks Tim Williams for correction but i want to check for the value of that cell then run certain conditions.

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("E4", Range("E4").End(xlDown))` is all of the cells between and including E4 and wherever Ctrl+Down takes you.

Comment: You can store ranges in `Range` objects so you don't have to repeat yourself, over and over again.

Comment: @HackSlash but i am changing my val1 and val2 within 2 different conditions that means i have to declare range objects once or twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BigBen said in the comments, it is down to your use of `If...Else...If` twice. The first correction is:

```
If Result = True And Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C4", Range("C4").End(xlDown)) <> "" Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4", Range("C4").End(xlDown)).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4", Range("C4").End(xlDown)). _
    Value + Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C4", Range("C4").End(xlDown)).Value
ElseIf Result = True And Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D4", Range("D4").End(xlDown)) <> "" Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D4", Range("D4").End(xlDown)).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D4", Range("D4").End(xlDown)). _
    Value + Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D4", Range("D4").End(xlDown)).Value
End If
```

Notice how your use of `Else` and `If` on separate lines has been replaced by `ElseIf`. And the second change is:

```
If Result = True And Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C4", Range("C4").End(xlDown)) <> "" Then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C4", Range("C4").End(xlDown)).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C4", Range("C4").End(xlDown)). _
    Value + Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C4", Range("C4").End(xlDown)).Value
ElseIf Result = True And Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D4", Range("D4").End(xlDown)) <> "" Then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D4", Range("D4").End(xlDown)).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D4", Range("D4").End(xlDown)). _
    Value + Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D4", Range("D4").End(xlDown)).Value
End If
```

Also, you are declaring `val1`,`val2` and `result` twice in this sub - you only need to declare them once.

Regards,

Comment: Thank you @Applecore but then how to write the code, appreciate much more if you just correct me by writing the corrected code, btw first I declared them once in the sub then i thought i have to change the values of the range that is why i declared them twice.

Comment: The two code snippets that I posted are the corrected versions - you will need to paste them into your own code.

Comment: Apology for the my mistake @Applecore thanks again i will check then revert back to you.

Comment: Your answer is still problematic for the reasons that Tim [pointed out above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61089213/automate-quantity-of-any-items-using-excel-vba#comment108076199_61089213). Most likely OP wants a loop.

Comment: Yes, but solve one problem at a time :)

Comment: @BigBen that means my code could not run with if then else statement and must requires loop?